# What differences between these two ways of object declaration?

Tags: javascript, json

I was just wondering if there are any differences between these ways of `JSON` object declaration or they do the same thing? What is the standard (**recommended**) way to declare an object?

According to my test, they both give the same result.

```
let data1 = {
  "record_1": [1,2,3],
  "record_2": [4,5,6]
}

let data2 = {
  record_1: [1,2,3],
  record_2: [4,5,6]
}

console.log(data1);
console.log(data2);
console.log(data1.record_1);
console.log(data2.record_1);
console.log(data1.record_2);
console.log(data2.record_2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(data2));
```

Output:

```
{
record_1:(3) [...],
record_2:(3) [...]
}
{
record_1:(3) [...],
record_2:(3) [...]
}
(3) [
1,
2,
3
]
(3) [
1,
2,
3
]
(3) [
4,
5,
6
]
(3) [
4,
5,
6
]
{"record_1":[1,2,3],"record_2":[4,5,6]}
{"record_1":[1,2,3],"record_2":[4,5,6]}
```

Comment: The first is mainly for properties, which would result in invalid syntax: `{ "i have spaces and : colons": "value" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the declarations are valid in Javascript

```
let data1 = {
  "record_1": [1,2,3],
  "record_2": [4,5,6]
}

let data2 = {
  record_1: [1,2,3],
  record_2: [4,5,6]
}
```

but when it comes to JSON , `data2` is invalid JSON syntax. You can verify at https://jsonlint.com/

One more diff is as below:

```
var obj = { "some key" : "Val" };  // Valid in JS

var obj = { some key : "Val" }; // invalid in JS
```

So for JS , both of these deceleration plays different role depending on the situation. Normally, `data2` type declaration is widely used.

Answer (score 3):

Object's property name are of type *string*, if you provide any other type then that is automatically converted to *string*.

```js
var obj = {1: "one"}
var keyName = Object.keys(obj)[0];
console.log(`key Name ${keyName} and type is ${typeof keyName}`);
```

I will prefer the explicit way (using the quotes) of declaration as this will reduced the confusion (from the reader of the code).

Answer (score 1):

They're essentially the same. One difference is that when you use quotes, you can use special characters as key.

```
// invalid
const noQuotes = {
    key with spaces: 123
}

// valid
const withQuotes = {
    "key with spaces": 123
}
```